# How to remove block in view page in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

[image]

I need to remove social shares from product view page in magento2

Comment: hi @Mano M please try the below answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `catalog_product_view.xml` file in your custom theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="product.info.social" remove="true" />
</page>
```